# What is the probability mass function of Rock, Paper, Scissors?

Tags: probability, density-function, joint-distribution

I  was curious about the statistics behind the game of rock, paper, scissors. Let's say n people are playing, where n is greater than or equal to 2. If when all n people reveal their play and only 1 or all 3 options appear, that round is deemed indecisive, and they just play again. If when all people reveal their hand and two of the three options appear, that round is decisive, and those with the winning play continue and those with the losing play are eliminated. Playing continues until only one person remains.

If we assume that the game begins with n = 10 people, and they each independently and randomly choose between the three options with equal probability, and let R, P, and S count the number of players who play rock, paper, and scissors, respectively.

How would you work out the joint PMF of R, P, and S?

Comment: Search for information on the *multinomial distribution.*